# products with multiple option filters mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I am setting up a database with the following layout:

prodCategory (ID,name)
prodsToCategory (cat_id, prod_id)
Products (ID, name, desc etc)
prodsToOptions (prod_id, cat_id)
prodOptions (ID, type, name)

I am looking for the most efficient mysql query to join the tables and return only the products with what options have been selected.

I currently have:

```
  SELECT
    p.ID,
    p.name,
    p.description,
    p.code,
    po.name
  FROM
    Products p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN prodsToCategory pc ON p.ID = pc.product_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN prodsToOptions pto ON p.ID = pto.product_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN prodOptions po ON pto.option_id = po.ID
  WHERE   p.active = '1'
  AND     pc.category_id = '1'
  AND     (po.name = 'black' OR po.name = 'blue')
  GROUP BY p.ID
```

The url would look something like this:

www.test.com/cars?options=black-blue-manual etc (posted with ajax)

The above query does work but i'm sure there is a cleaner way of doing it when more options are set.

Any suggestions are gratefully received, even if the DB schema need changing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: a.) Make sure your tables are properly indexed. 2. ) Use EXPLAIN queries to optimize your queries and make sure they're using the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Use, `AND po.name IN('black','blue')`

Comment: Is IN more efficient than OR?